# How to plot multiple column barplots under same labels

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm looking to plot my dataframe, which contains many columns each with a "TRUE" or "FALSE" label (imported from Excel).

A small example of something similar would be this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":["TRUE","FALSE","FALSE","TRUE","FALSE"],
"b":["TRUE","TRUE","FALSE","TRUE","TRUE"],
"c":["TRUE","FALSE","FALSE","FALSE","TRUE"],
"d":["FALSE","FALSE","TRUE","TRUE","FALSE"]})
```

I'm looking for a way to concisely summarize how the TRUE and FALSE values are distributed between the columns. Ideally, a graph like something below would be created:

[image: Example of what I'm looking for]

but I'm unsure how to create this. I've tried list comprehension, like trying

`sns.barplot([list(df[i].value_counts()) for i in df.columns])`

but get something entirely different. I don't even need to know how to make the legend, I just included it in the example to hopefully better portray what I'm getting after.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a 2-bin histogram

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
df.stack().groupby(level=1).value_counts().unstack(0).plot.bar()
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You had the more efficient approach already in your attempt.  You *should* be computing the `value_counts` on each series if you want to scale this to larger frames.  You just need a change to the `plot`.

```
f = pd.concat(
      [df[s].value_counts() for s in df], axis=1, sort=False)

f.plot(kind='bar')
```